# PNG and JPG quality loss inserting webpage screenshot into LaTeX document

Tags: graphics, png, jpeg

I have tried using both a png and jpg file format for my images but I still loose a significant amount of quality when I run pdflatex.  Is there some way to work around this?

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bindingoffset=15.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
I have some text here.  Then pics.
\newpage
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75, angle=90, width=\textwidth]{hamlet.jpg}
\caption{cool picture}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75, angle=270, width=\textwidth]{kinglear.jpg}
\caption{cool picture 2}
\end{figure}
\newpage
some more text here
\end{document}
```

Here is my png image
[image: king lear png]

and here is the output of my pdflatex run (the rotation is intentional in the pdf)
[image: king lear pdf]

Comment: Text in a `png` or `jpg` file always becomes distorted if you scale the image.

Comment: Ahh.  So should I set the width instead of scaling the image?  I did not realize that I was doing both.

Comment: I got rid of the scaling but the output is still shoddy.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Whith your MWE and your JPEG picture, I see no difference between the original picture and the same picture included by LaTeX into a PDF...

Comment: `png` and `jpg` images have an 'actual' size. They will suffer distortion if they are displayed at any other size, and the distortion is worst if the image contains text. An application such as photoshop may do a better job of resizing the image, but some distortion is inevitable.

Comment: @PolGab I am using TeXStudio.  Do you think that could be why?

Comment: @IanThompson I thought using a png format would prevent the severe distortion that I am seeing though?

Comment: Which PDF viewer did you use to produce the "bad" image?

Comment: @PolGab Adobe Acrobat

Comment: `png` is a bitmap format. Text in bitmaps distorts if you rescale the image.

Comment: Having said that, I just tried your MWE and the distortion is not so bad.

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder why mine is so skewed.  I tried making the original image smaller, but I am still not having much success with getting it clearer.  Would putting the image in a pdf format be better than a png or jpg?

Comment: It depends on how the image is generated. If your application has an option to export as `pdf` (or `eps`) you should get a better result.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I tried a pdf but I get the same result.  I might try it on a different computer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**LaTeX graphics packages**

LaTeX and its graphics packages do not touch the image data. TeX does not even provide
the reading of binary data. Thus LaTeX passes the image as file name reference to
the driver. Also most of the drivers are not image processing programs. They only move
the image data in a form appropriate for the output format. For example, dvips only
copies the PostScript file into the output PostScript file. Also pdfTeX often do not
need to unpack the image data and can copy the data to the PDF structures. Some PNG
files are uncompressed and compressed. But this process does not change the image data.

**Driver issues**
Very view drivers are able to resize an image, AFAIK Acrobat Distiller and
GhostScript does some obscure things with images like using JPEG compression for
PNG images. I do not know how this can be turned off. The related options given in Ps2pdf.htm
seems to have no effect.

But you are using pdflatex that does not change the image data.
This can be tested. Take a PNG image and convert it to PPM. Also embed
the image in a LaTeX document and run pdflatex. The program pdfimages (xpdf)
extract the image in PPM format.

```
convert image.png image.ppm
pdflatex test.tex
pdfimages test.pdf t
diff t-000.ppm image.ppm
```

The files `t-000.ppm` and `image.ppm` should be identical, if the PPM format
is the same (there is a binary and an ASCII variant).

** Different viewing programs**
However the programs
to view the images are different. The image viewer and the PDF viewer are usually
different programs that uses different methods for viewing. For example, a program
might use anti-aliasing, …

**Scaling vs. resizing**

There are no problems in scaling images in LaTeX independent of its method:

- Option `scale`
- Options `width`, `height`
- `\scalebox`
- …

Only the place that the image uses on the page differs, the image data
remains the same.

A different term is the resizing of an image. Then the actual number of pixels
change. Of course, an image processing program cannot invent missing details
if the image is enlarged. It can only use better or worse methods to limit
the artefacts of resizing.

**Screenshots**

Screens have low resolutions comparing to printed media and are usually
stupid bitmap images of the pixels on the screen even if the original
data were high quality vector data (non-pixel fonts, vector drawings).

Some hints to get better quality:

- In some cases a vector screenshot program might be available, e.g. gtk-vector-screenshot.
- A special case are web pages. They could be converted to PDF by printing or
  there are programs/sites that perform the conversion. But caution, PDF, especially
  PDFs from screenshot programs might contain bitmap data instead.
- Higher screen resolution with larger font/symbol settings or using settings
  for visually impaired people.
- A large monitor helps that allows large windows for the screenshot programs that
  can only catch the pixels inside the screen.
- And it can make sense to turn off anti-aliasing and similar (ClearType) to
  get clean pixel data. Thus that a black line is displayed by black pixels and
  not by many gray levels at its edges. That makes it easier to optimize the
  image for the final media.

Comment: Thank you.  I created a high quality pdf with Nitro http://www.nitropdf.com/ and it seems to work better

Comment: @Wrigley242 With detailed explanations of Heiko, I do not understand why you need software like Nitro.

Comment: «pdflatex that does not change the image data. This can be tested… pdfimages… diff»
I made an experiment [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350379/lossless-includegraphics-for-png-without-conversion-for-pdflatex-xelatex] and found that xeatex/pdflatex change source PNG images.  What is wrong?

Comment: @StasFomin Wrong test. Image data and the representation of the image data in a file are different. Additionally, a file can have comments, additional meta-data, ... Also, the image file formats can have some flexibility: order of chunks, ... A test based on the conversion to [PNM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) is more close to the issue.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek, please look at [https://github.com/belonesox/xelatex-and-graphics-quality/blob/master/test.sh] — I compared images not by text diff but by `compare` from imagemagick, and get very nonempty diff-png https://github.com/belonesox/xelatex-and-graphics-quality/blob/master/diff.png

Metadata, order of chunks, etc…  is not an explanation for this.

Comment: @StasFomin `identify -verbose lenna.png` shows, that the PNG file also contains a gamma and a chromaticy chunk. `xdvipdfmx` (XeLaTeX) adds these data to the image dictionary of the generated PDF file, whereas pdfTeX does *not*. The image data (color values of the pixels) are the same. `lenna.pnm` from `convert lenna.png lenna.pnm` is equal to files, extracted by `pngimages`.

Answer (score 4):

Whith your MWE and your JPEG picture, I see no difference between the original picture and the same picture included by LaTeX into a PDF...

Here is the result:

[image]

Verify that "Smooth images" is checked in "Page Display" category of Adobe Reader preferences.

Comment: Hello, yes it is.